# jQuery Transparent Menu on Scroll Up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What I am trying to achieve is something similar to this: http://www.thoughtspot.com/

I'm nearly there! What I can't replicate is how the navigation has a transparent background when scrolling up and then it disappears.

Could anyone assist me on this?

```
function hasScrolled() {
var st = $(this).scrollTop();

// Make sure they scroll more than delta
if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
    return;

// If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
// This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
    // Scroll Down
    $('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
} else {
    // Scroll Up
    if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
        $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
    }
}

lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

For the full code please view the jsfiddle I have created:

http://jsfiddle.net/s6mLJ/2257/

Thanks everyone!

Comment: try adding `.animate({opacity: 0})` before `.addClass()` on your scroll down and `opacity: 1` on your scroll up.

Comment: Here's one approach : http://jsfiddle.net/s6mLJ/2258/. I made the interval a bit shorter for predictability. Any browser should easily be able to handle ten calculations a second.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Press - I couldn't get that to work. 

$('header').removeClass('nav-down').animate({opacity: 0}).addClass('nav-up');

 $('header').removeClass('nav-up').animate({opacity: 1}).addClass('nav-down');

Comment: The background will have to be a separate element for not everything inside the header to become opaque...

Comment: @Shikkediel - Yes that is a way, although it didn't seem to work when I scrolled down and up, down and up, over and over again.

Comment: You're right, there was a quirk. But it seems to work within the interval. http://jsfiddle.net/s6mLJ/2260/. Sometimes when scrolling down, the effect isn't great though. Might wanna tweak the interval time with the top offset for setting the background again.

Comment: If I may add, I think you should reverse the logic with the interval and checking if the page has been scrolled. This will go on as long as someone's visiting and is a pretty big memory leak. Best to clear the interval when nothing's happening on the scroll front.

Answer (score 0):

here you go just add opacity to the classes and css transition handles the rest:

```
opacity: 0
```

I have also added a linear transparent background, to make it similar to your example.

http://jsfiddle.net/s6mLJ/2262/

NEW VERSION
http://jsfiddle.net/s6mLJ/2313/

Comment: It's not quite there! - The background should be transparent when you scroll back up to the top. Just like the website example I posted above. Thanks.

Comment: The linear gradient is a nice idea but this isn't really an answer. Nothing is happening otherwise to replicate the behaviour mentioned.

Comment: ok so I guess only the BG goes transparent, no issue, same priciple just set a new BG color:
http://jsfiddle.net/s6mLJ/2266/

P.S. I made some changes to better see the effect

Comment: @Shikkediel I really did not add the gradient on purpose I guess I had an older version of the OP fiddle (there seam to be quite a few of them :D)

Comment: Okay then... it seems your fiddle sort of does the opposite from the example page though. There the header fades out when the top of the pages is reached instead of when scrolling down.

Comment: ok, I don't get it scroll about mid way down to the page and then slightly up and down both on the fiddle and the example I fail to see what the difference in behaviour is. .... but i'm sure if I see it I can show you how it's done. I just don't see any difference

Comment: @tripleb - this works really well but the background should be hidden when it's at the top.

Comment: ok I updated it, didn't notice the fact that it was transarent on top,